# Gettext russian language

Tags: php, gettext

I managed my site to work with `gettext`. Currently there is only the English to Hungarian translation, which is working like a charm, and a half-completed Russian translation which is just not loading.

I am passing the variables via url, like url.php?lang=hu. If I load the russian translation into the hungarian translation's folder, it do something but showing only ??? characters. I know, I need to set it to utf-8 and i found a bunch of question here related to this topic but i couldnt solve this. my folders are:

hu_HU > LC_MESSAGES > messages.po/mo 
ru_RU > LC_MESSAGES > messages.po/mo

And the code is: (maybe this would be easier to replace to "$locale = $_GET['lang'];" :))

```
    switch ($lang) {

  case 'hu':
  $locale = "hu_HU";
    if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
    textdomain("messages");
  break;

  case 'ru':
  $locale = "ru_RU";
    if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale.'.utf8');
    bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
    textdomain("messages");
  break;

}
```

** *EDIT ****

After I read so much about this, I called my hosting company. They switched on the requested languages. Now the russian is working, but it is not recognize the ciril letters. Putting the meta charset is solving the problem but in this case special characters, like öüóőúéáű are not showing properly. I tried to change the code to utf8 around the setlocal but there is no success. What can be the solution?

```
$locale = "ru_RU.UTF-8";
    if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale, 'UTF-8');
    bindtextdomain("messages", "locale");
    textdomain("messages");
```

And my folder structure for it is: ru_RU.UTF-8 > LC_MESSAGES > messages.po/mo

Comment: If you are using this in a web site context, to you set the charset option in the content-type header as well, depending on the locale?

Comment: Guntram, thank you for helping. I cannot put utf-8 into meta charset, because if I do, special characters like öüóőúéáű are not showing properly. According to my tries, putting the utf-8 into meta tag changes nothing, the Russian language file just not load :( I have to name the folders or change the code above.